# Cannot read compressed bz2 file from http://archive.routeviews.org/

Tags: python, ascii, bzip2, bgp

For class we are to download these 54MB .bz2 files from routeviews.

When I unzip the .bz2 files they are in .0000 format and around 500MB. When I -tail -f the output its a bunch of garbage.

How can I convert these data to ascii so I can start working with it?

This is what I get when I tail the file:
�xx��1'1/�1/�1/�1/�1N 1��1��w@����'R��+S@P
                                 R��2%@P-�+�1��w@`7R���!@P1��w@P[�>"R���%@P�1��w@�>��-R���!@P1��w@����R���,@PX|5���+R�`

Comment: `bzip2 -d filename.bz2` tried this ?

Comment: Yes I've tried that already and it just decompresses the file. I need the decompressed file to be readable as standard output/ascii/etc. The file that results is a binary file.

Comment: Then its not a readable text file. It seems to be encrypted or further compressed. Try `file fileName.0000` on your file. That would tell what format the file is.

Answer (score 0):

Hope this helps now.

You are trying to read an MRT file. This can be done using this-

https://github.com/YoshiyukiYamauchi/mrtparse/blob/master/examples/print_all.py

And the docs for the same is here:-
https://github.com/YoshiyukiYamauchi/mrtparse